# cygwin64 on Windows server, syslog data prints out all in one line

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cygwin, syslog-ng, cygwin-sshd

I am trying to automatically format syslog data from cygwin64 to print out with line breaks at the end of each line, so I can do some parsing later on. However, I don't see any configs that could yield a solution. How can I properly format the syslog data?

Comment: Hi, could you clarify the problem and the environment a bit?
From the tags I guess that you are running sshd under cygwin, and use syslog-ng to write the logs into a file, but there is some problem with the line breaks. Is that right?

Comment: I apologize @RobertFekete, I should have been more specific. Yes you are correct, sshd with syslog-ng. I am checking the /var/log/messages directory to see the writing of the sys log data to a text file, but it all comes up on one line, rather than one line per sys log message. Should I provide any more specifics? Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: Do you use any specific template to format the messages? It might be that the linebreak character (\n) is not handled properly on windows. Try adding a \r to the template, for example: 
destination d_file {
    file ("/var/log/messages" template("${ISODATE} ${HOST} ${MSG}\r\n") );
};

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Please post it as answer so I can give some rep! @RobertFekete

Comment: Glad that it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use any specific template to format the messages? It might be that the linebreak character (\n) is not handled properly on windows. Try adding a \r to the template, for example:

```
destination d_file { file ("/var/log/messages" template("${ISODATE} ${HOST} ${MSG}\r\n") ); };
```

Comment: I just realized I have 13 rep and I need 15 to give you rep! lol sorry. I'll upvote this soon!